# WPF combobox extra space between entries

Tags: wpf

I have a combobox that is filled with a handful of entries, but some of them have quite a bit of whitespace between them.

[image]

This space is still visible even after I change the font size.  Below is the XAML code:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" DisplayMemberPath="[ColumnName]" 
 FontSize="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=[TableName], NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" Width="250"/>
```

where ColumnName and TableName come from my table in SQL.

In the view model I have this code:

```
PropertyInViewModel = DataModel.TableName.ToList();
```

where my property in my view model is this:

```
private IEnumerable<TableName> _propertyInViewModel;
public IEnumerable<TableName> ProptertyInViewModel
{
    get { return _propertyInViewModel; }
    set { _propertyInViewModel= value; this.RaisePropertyChanged(); }
}
```

I have another column in this table that is simply a primary key for the entries in the picture above.  If I display the primary keys, I don't have the extra space.  I'm not sure what the issue is, but changing the font size and the combobox's width did not seem to fix the issue.  Any help would be great!

Comment: Do you got linefeeds at the end of the data?

Comment: After querying the database for other entries, some of them had newlines... Don't ask me how they got there.  It makes no sense, but that was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your XAML.

Make sure that the source collection doesn't include any records where the `ColumnName` property returns an empty `string` or `null`

Also make sure that the other records don't include any empty lines.

Comment: The newlines did not show up in my table in SQL or in Server Explorer in Visual Studio.  To view the new lines, I had to view the result from the DataModel.TableName.ToList();  From there I looped through the entries and trimmed the correct column.  Now it displays nicely.